# Pg_read_file no such file or directory error?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION j_f_sync_from_xml()
RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
myxml    xml;
datafile text := 'ABBATE_EMANUELE.xml';
BEGIN

myxml := pg_read_file(datafile, 0, 100000000); 

CREATE TABLE james AS
SELECT (xpath('//some_id/text()', x))[1]::text AS id
FROM   unnest(xpath('/xml/path/to/datum', myxml)) x;
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

The directory is C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\data and I insert the file 'ABBATE_EMANUELE.xml' in the path. I tried with other files but it doesn't function.

Comment: please quote exact error you get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't reproduce.

checking dir:

```
postgres=# show data_directory;
 data_directory
----------------
 /pg/d10
(1 row)
```

and now creating file and reading it:

```
postgres=# \! echo $(date) > /pg/d10/test

postgres=# do $$ declare c text; df text := 'test';
begin
c := pg_read_file(df);
raise info '%', c;
end;
$$
;
INFO:  Tue Nov 28 09:59:30 UTC 2017
```

Comment: my data directory is 'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/data'

Comment: please post result of `select pg_ls_dir('C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/data')`

Comment: "base"
"global"
"pg_clog"
"pg_dynshmem"
"pg_hba.conf"
"pg_ident.conf"
"pg_log"
"pg_logical"
"pg_multixact"
"pg_notify"
"pg_replslot"
"pg_serial"
"pg_snapshots"
"pg_stat"
"pg_stat_tmp"
"pg_subtrans"
"pg_tblspc"
"pg_twophase"
"PG_VERSION"
"pg_xlog"
"postgresql.auto.conf"
"postgresql.conf"
"postmaster.opts"
"postmaster.pid"

Comment: I don't see `ABBATE_EMANUELE.xml` between them, please post result of `dir C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/data` in command line

Comment: there is ABBATE_EMANUELE.xml in the directory... i tried also to read a log file in the path 'C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/data/pg_log and also not read the file

Comment: check permissions and ownership

Comment: I don't write on server, not on local

Comment: if you can upload file to SERVER PGDATA directory, you can't load it with `pg_read_file`

Comment: i can't write on server, only on local

Comment: then you can't use function saved on server for that